# Sometimes PKExec does nothing and just hangs, is this a bug?

Tags: 18.04, bug-reporting, pkexec

Sometimes when I run

```
$ pkexec echo test
```

(it happens with any program) after the computer has been on for a while, no graphical dialogue "Authentication required" appears, and pkexec just hangs forever, printing nothing to the console and doing nothing.

This is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Am I required to create a PolKit XML file for every application I want to run with PKExec to avoid this?

Is there an explanation, or is it a bug I should report?